# Is there a way for the text in a label to automatically update the display

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an app that lets users input 4 numbers and display what cellular network is that number. Is there a way to automatically display the numbers in the label after the user inputs the numbers without clicking a button? I actually have a code that lets the user input the number but the user must click the enter button for it to display the result on the label. Is there a way for it to automatically display the result? By the way, I'm actually new to swift so I apologize. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var numField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answerField: UILabel!

@IBAction func enterButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    matchNumber()
}

func matchNumber(){

    let number: String = numField.text!
    let numRef = Firebase(url: "https://npi2.firebaseio.com/num_details")
    numRef.queryOrderedByKey().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let network = snapshot.value as! String!
            if snapshot.key ==  self.numField.text! {
                self.answerField.text = network

            }
            else {
                self.answerField.text = "Missing"

            }

    })

    }
```

Comment: How are they inputting the numbers? Which label? Edit your question to show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I already edited it thank you @vacawama

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a target to your `numField`, something like this...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.numField.addTarget(self, action: "editingChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
}
```

This will trigger the `editingChanged` method every time a character changes in the `numField`.

```
func editingChanged(textField:UITextField) {
    if let text = textField.text {
        if text.characters.count == 4 {
            matchNumber()
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we check if there is a string in the input and if it is 4 characters long before running the `matchNumber` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the didSet method.

```
    var numberstring = String() {
    didSet {
        yourlabel.text = numberstring
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `textfield` to take input then you can use `textfieldDidEndEditing` delegate method.